# How do I solve the circuit below using nodal analysis?

Tags: circuit-analysis, nodal-analysis

I would like to know how I solve this circuit using nodal analysis

[image]
[source](https://holooly.com/solutions/solve-for-vo-in-the-circuit-of-fig-10-9-using-mesh-analysis/)

My attempt:

[image]

Comment: To get people to help you with homework, you need to show an attempt yourself first so we can see exactly where you're stuck, This isn't a site where people do your homework for you

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because homework needs to have an attempt at a solution

Comment: Also please provide a source for the image, otherwise its plagerisim

Comment: Are the crossing central wires connected?

Comment: @Andyaka I believe so since there is also example of mesh to this circuit

Comment: @winny not a homework just trying to solve this question in nodal other than mesh

Comment: @MCG, not homework just asking for educational advice on what I did wrong, but I forgot to put my attempt

Comment: If not homework, did your employer ask you to solve it?

Comment: What makes you think your solution is **not** correct? Have you tried running a simulation to verify it?

Comment: @winny I was passing my time and saw this circuit and the method used to solve which was mech analysis, i thought i should try nodal analysis to solve it and same time refresh my memories but I am not getting the same answer as mesh analysis after working on it for 5 hours

Comment: @elliotAlderson the reason is the answer I got from nodal analysis is not matching with mesh analysis answer, I believe i may made blunder at some stage while solving it, but after so much review I still can't find what's the issue. That's is why I was Kindly asking you guys

Comment: There is a link up which labeled source it's done in mesh analysis and final answer is different from what I get

Comment: @Sabretooth2438 I'll help. See below. I just got back; out for a day. So I'll pop this out quickly. Not too much explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Feel free to ask questions, if you have them. But what follows is nodal analysis, not mesh.

Assign \$0\:\text{V}\$ to the bottom node. You can do that to exactly one node. That's the one I pick.

[image]

Then I find these three nodal equations with three unknowns. And in this case, \$V_{_\text{O}}=V_{_\text{A}}\$:

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{V_{_\text{A}}}{8\:\Omega}+\frac{V_{_\text{A}}}{-j\,2\:\Omega}+\frac{V_{_\text{A}}}{j\,5\:\Omega}+4\:\text{A}&=\frac{10\:\text{V}}{8\:\Omega}+\frac{V_{_\text{C}}}{j\,5\:\Omega}
\\\\
\frac{V_{_\text{B}}}{6\:\Omega}+\frac{V_{_\text{B}}}{-j\,4\:\Omega}&=\frac{10\:\text{V}}{-j\,4\:\Omega}+\frac{V_{_\text{C}}}{6\:\Omega}+4\:\text{A}
\\\\
\frac{V_{_\text{C}}}{6\:\Omega}+\frac{V_{_\text{C}}}{j\,5\:\Omega}&=\frac{V_{_\text{A}}}{j\,5\:\Omega}+\frac{V_{_\text{B}}}{6\:\Omega}+3\:\text{A}
\end{align*}$$

Just stuff that into SymPy (yes, I can see Matlab in your link):

```
var('va vb vc')
eq1 = Eq( va/8 + va/(-2*I) + va/(5*I) + 4, 10/8 + vc/(5*I) )
eq2 = Eq( vb/6 + vb/(-4*I), 10/(-4*I) + vc/6 + 4 )
eq3 = Eq( vc/6 + vc/(5*I), va/(5*I) + vb/6 + 3 )
solve( [ eq1, eq2, eq3 ], [ va, vb, vc ] )
{va: -1046/145 - 952*I/145,
 vb: 4018/145 - 1084*I/145,
 vc: 2164/145 + 2768*I/145}
solve( [ eq1, eq2, eq3 ], [ va, vb, vc ] )[va].n()
-7.21379310344828 - 6.56551724137931*I
```

That answer matches the one you linked towards:

[image]

And my calculator says:

```
-7.21379310344828 - 6.56551724137931j
-7.2137931 - j6.56551724, 9.75422101 < -137.693611
```

Comment: I was getting this "9.75422101 < -137.693611" instead of the "9.756 < 222.32
That is why I assumed something was wrong with my calculations.
Is there a way to have a positive angle in the calculator or is this how it is supposed to give you an answer?

Comment: @Sabretooth2438 Either is fine to me. I don't know if there is a preferred custom. But I tend to prefer keeping it within -180 to +180. I think it may be different in different places in the world. I'm honestly not sure if there is a globally accepted standard. I've certainly not encountered it.

Comment: It's a self-preference, but thank you for the help because of a simple thing that I forgot I thought my answer was wrong

Comment: @Sabretooth2438 Sounds as though you were fine, then. If you have to stick these numbers into some program, you will need to give what it expects. So that means conforming to whatever the programmer decided was "right" for the answer. If this were presented to a teacher (a human one) then I think they would easily recognize a correct answer, either way. Best wishes!